# Running remote_api_shell.py with gevent

Tags: google-app-engine, gevent

I have a relatively simple script I use to run map jobs over my data, and I'd like it to run a faster by using gevent to make reads from the datastore non-blocking.

I tried adding `gevent.monkey.patch_socket()` to the top of `remote_api_shell.py`, but after I log in, it throws a `urllib2.URLError` ([traceback](https://gist.github.com/4338945)).

I'm new to both GAE and gevent. Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Could someone point me in the right direction to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If using `ndb`:

You can use `ndb` with [`*_async` datastore operations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async):
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async

For example, to retrieve a list of elements by key:

```
ndb.get_multi_async(list_of_keys)
```

The great thing with `ndb` is that every datastore operation on keys or entities has an async equivalent.

### If using `db`:

You can use the [Async Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/async).

For example, to retrieve a list of elements by key:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
db.get_async(list_of_keys)
```

Where `list_of_keys` contains elements that are either strings, instances of `google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Key`, or instances of  `google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity`.

Similarly you can use `db.put_async` on lists of entities and `db.delete_async` on lists similar to those for `db.get_async`.

Comment: This is certainly an option, but I'd rather find a solution that doesn't involve migrating all of my model classes to ndb....

Comment: See the update. Though I implore you, please, **please**, **PLEASE** take the time to check out `ndb`. It is head and shoulders a better datastore API and gives you caching that you don't have to think about right out of the box.

Comment: Cool, I'll definitely check it out, thanks for the tip, and the thorough answer, as well!